# ComboBox.SelectedIndex does not appear in properties window? (C# Form, VS 2013)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, combobox

I want to make a default value for my ComboBox on my C# form I am making using Visual Studio 2013.  I read that the SelectedIndex property is what I should be using, however, I do not see the SelectedIndex property in the properties window.

Thanks,
BobTheLawyer

Comment: You can't set it in the Designer because to make any sense it would have to rely on the Item to actually be there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm getting the same behavior in the designer of VS2013 in that the SelectedIndex or SelectedValue property doesn't show in the properties window.  You can easily create your own method which I call `MyIntializeComponent()` method in  `formName.cs` file.  I create this type of method when I want to change or create my own controls on a form initially created in the VS designer.

Code in your FormName.cs file:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyInitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyInitializeComponent()
    {
        // Add your desired properties here.
        this.combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        // OR
        this.combobox1.SelectedValue = "1";
    }
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work well (although I wish there was a way to do this in the properties instead of adding more code for every combobox), but VisualStudio seems to rewrite the designer.cs, so I don't want to have to make these changes every time.

Comment: Good call on the designer wanting to change the code all the time.  I've made an edit above.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedIndex property can be set or get by code like:

```
           this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Where the value is the item number 0 in the combo-box.